# Wordpress Menu Description in Dropdown

Tags: wordpress

I'm looking to display the Menu Description in the Dropdown for my menu.

I'm using a Nav Menu Walker with a dropdown that supports Bootstrap for my current menu and I have an example of a Nav Menu Walker with just the description.

How would I go about putting the Description into the dropdown links? (Link - description)

Here is the walker with the description:

```
         $class_names = $value = '';

         $classes = empty( $item->classes ) ? array() : (array) $item->classes;

         $class_names = join( ' ', apply_filters( 'nav_menu_css_class', array_filter( $classes ), $item ) );
         $class_names = ' class="'. esc_attr( $class_names ) . '"';

         $output .= $indent . '<li id="menu-item-'. $item->ID . '"' . $value . $class_names .'>';

         $attributes  = ! empty( $item->attr_title ) ? ' title="'  . esc_attr( $item->attr_title ) .'"' : '';
         $attributes .= ! empty( $item->target )     ? ' target="' . esc_attr( $item->target     ) .'"' : '';
         $attributes .= ! empty( $item->xfn )        ? ' rel="'    . esc_attr( $item->xfn        ) .'"' : '';
         $attributes .= ! empty( $item->url )        ? ' href="'   . esc_attr( $item->url        ) .'"' : '';

         $prepend = '<strong>';
         $append = '</strong>';
         $description  = ! empty( $item->description ) ? '<span>'.esc_attr( $item->description ).'</span>' : '';

         if($depth != 0)
         {
                $description = $append = $prepend = "";
         }

          $item_output = $args->before;
          $item_output .= '<a'. $attributes .'>';
          $item_output .= $args->link_before .$prepend.apply_filters( 'the_title', $item->title, $item->ID ).$append;
          $item_output .= $description.$args->link_after;
          $item_output .= '</a>';
          $item_output .= $args->after;

          $output .= apply_filters( 'walker_nav_menu_start_el', $item_output, $item, $depth, $args );
          }
```

}

Here is my current walker:

```
class wp_bootstrap_navwalker extends Walker_Nav_Menu {

        /* Start of the <ul>
         *
         * Note on $depth: Counterintuitively, $depth here means the "depth right before we start this menu".
         *                 So basically add one to what you'd expect it to be
         */
        function start_lvl(&$output, $depth) {
            $tabs = str_repeat("\t", $depth);
            // If we are about to start the first submenu, we need to give it a dropdown-menu class
            if ($depth == 0 || $depth == 1) { //really, level-1 or level-2, because $depth is misleading here (see note above)
                $output .= "\n{$tabs}<ul class=\"dropdown-menu\">\n";
            } else {
                $output .= "\n{$tabs}<ul>\n";
            }

            return;
        }

        /* End of the <ul>
         *
         * Note on $depth: Counterintuitively, $depth here means the "depth right before we start this menu".
         *                 So basically add one to what you'd expect it to be
         */
        function end_lvl(&$output, $depth) {
            if ($depth == 0) { // This is actually the end of the level-1 submenu ($depth is misleading here too!)

                // we don't have anything special for Bootstrap, so we'll just leave an HTML comment for now
                $output .= '<!--.dropdown-->';
            }
            $tabs = str_repeat("\t", $depth);
            $output .= "\n{$tabs}</ul>\n";

            return;
        }

        /* Output the <li> and the containing <a>
         * Note: $depth is "correct" at this level
         */
        function start_el(&$output, $item, $depth, $args) {
            global $wp_query;
            $indent      = ($depth) ? str_repeat("\t", $depth) : '';
            $class_names = $value = '';
            $classes     = empty($item->classes) ? array() : (array)$item->classes;

            /* If this item has a dropdown menu, add the 'dropdown' class for Bootstrap */
            if ($item->hasChildren) {
                $classes[] = 'dropdown';
                // level-1 menus also need the 'dropdown-submenu' class
                if ($depth == 1) {
                    $classes[] = 'dropdown-submenu';
                }
            }

            $prepend     = '<strong>';
            $append      = '</strong>';
            $description = !empty($item->description) ? '<span>' . esc_attr($item->description) . '</span>' : '';

            if ($depth != 0) {
                $description = $append = $prepend = "";
            }

            /* This is the stock Wordpress code that builds the <li> with all of its attributes */
            $class_names = join(' ', apply_filters('nav_menu_css_class', array_filter($classes), $item));
            $class_names = ' class="' . esc_attr($class_names) . '"';
            $output .= $indent . '<li id="menu-item-' . $item->ID . '"' . $value . $class_names . '>';
            $attributes = !empty($item->attr_title) ? ' title="' . esc_attr($item->attr_title) . '"' : '';
            $attributes .= !empty($item->target) ? ' target="' . esc_attr($item->target) . '"' : '';
            $attributes .= !empty($item->xfn) ? ' rel="' . esc_attr($item->xfn) . '"' : '';
            $attributes .= !empty($item->url) ? ' href="' . esc_attr($item->url) . '"' : '';
            $item_output = $args->before;

            /* If this item has a dropdown menu, make clicking on this link toggle it */
            if ($item->hasChildren && $depth == 0) {
                $item_output .= '<a' . $attributes . ' class="dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown">';
            } else {
                $item_output .= '<a' . $attributes . '>';
            }

            $item_output .= $args->link_before . apply_filters('the_title', $item->title, $item->ID) . $args->link_after;

            /* Output the actual caret for the user to click on to toggle the menu */
            if ($item->hasChildren && $depth == 0) {
                $item_output .= '<b class="caret"></b></a>';
            } else {
                $item_output .= '</a>';
            }

            $item_output .= $args->after;
            $output .= apply_filters('walker_nav_menu_start_el', $item_output, $item, $depth, $args);

            return;
        }

        /* Close the <li>
         * Note: the <a> is already closed
         * Note 2: $depth is "correct" at this level
         */
        function end_el(&$output, $item, $depth, $args) {
            $output .= '</li>';

            return;
        }

        /* Add a 'hasChildren' property to the item
         * Code from: http://wordpress.org/support/topic/how-do-i-know-if-a-menu-item-has-children-or-is-a-leaf#post-3139633
         */
        function display_element($element, &$children_elements, $max_depth, $depth = 0, $args, &$output) {
            // check whether this item has children, and set $item->hasChildren accordingly
            $element->hasChildren = isset($children_elements[$element->ID]) && !empty($children_elements[$element->ID]);

            // continue with normal behavior
            return parent::display_element($element, $children_elements, $max_depth, $depth, $args, $output);
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is not entirely clear where you want to put the description, but, for example, if you wanted it after the link title, you could do something like the following in your Walker in the `start_el` function:

Where you currently have:

```
/* If this item has a dropdown menu, make clicking on this link toggle it */
if ($item->hasChildren && $depth == 0) {
    $item_output .= '<a' . $attributes . ' class="dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown">';
} else {
    $item_output .= '<a' . $attributes . '>';
}

$item_output .= $args->link_before . apply_filters('the_title', $item->title, $item->ID) . $args->link_after;
```

Replace the last line with:

```
$item_output .= $args->link_before . apply_filters('the_title', $item->title, $item->ID);
$item_output .= ' - <span class="desc">' . $item->description . '</span>';    
$item_output .= $args->link_after;
```

This inserts the menu_item description after the title (like `title - description`).

If you only want the description on sub-menus, use this variation:

```
$item_output .= $args->link_before . apply_filters('the_title', $item->title, $item->ID);
if ($depth > 0) {
    $item_output .= ' - <span class="desc">' . $item->description . '</span>';    
}
$item_output .= $args->link_after;
```

Comment: In my post I included two big code blocks,  In the second one I want to add it in that code. I'm not sure where exactly to put it so it only shows on items in the drop down menus. For the first depth, I don't want descriptions. Hope that helps make it more clear